# what this 2 empty [] mean?

Tags: transactions, protocol, reveal

[image]

when invoke with rpc api GET ..//operations.  always has 2 emtpy [].  what this mean?

I only care transaction. please tell me kind:transaction  is locate index where(must include in last index--index3?).  and what difference between kind:reveal and kind transaction?

Comment: Your question contains two questions, could you reformulate it as only one ?

Comment: Given cago's answer, it might be a good idea to reformulate the question to ask about what goes in the operations hash instead? It probably has more generic values.

Answer (score 14):

The first list contains the endorsements.

The second list contains all the operations regarding votes and proposals.

The third list contains anonymous operations.

The last one contains the manager operations (reveal, transaction, delegation and origination).

If you need to check only the transactions, you should check only the last one.

Comment: I think that's what they call "the multipass validation", they first validate the first list of operations (to check that the fitness is correct), and if the block is still the best one, you can start validating the other operations by order of importance.

Answer (score 5):

Difference between reveal and transaction:

When a wallet sends a transaction, it must sign the transaction with the user's private key. However, there is no way for other users to check the signature, if they don't have the corresponding public key. That's why the wallet must issue a Reveal operation first, to reveal the public key of the user.

Comment: thanks very much.  My exchange want to list tezos. thanks u detail answer.

Comment: is mean when a wallet send a transaction,must have 2 kind operation(reveal and transaction)?  is confusing...

Comment: If you are working for an exchange, maybe you should contract with Tezos tech advisors, that could help you build your plateform. Looks like you have too many questions and too broad for this forum. My company does that...