# What are anonymous operations?

Tags: operation

It is referenced in [this](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/368/what-this-2-empty-mean/372#372) answer about using `rpc api GET ..//operations`.

> The first list contains the endorsements.
>
> The second list contains all the operations regarding votes and proposals.
>
> The third list contains anonymous operations.
>
> The last one contains the manager operations (reveal, transaction, delegation and origination).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anonymous operations are operations that are not signed. There are three kinds of such operations: a seed nonce revelation, a double baking evidence, and a double endorsing evidence.